# How to read after a certain character in a file

Tags: java, regex

Hi i'm trying to read some credentials of a file, but i only want to read the data after the semi colon. So i was thinking of reading line by line and using REGEX but not too sure how to do this.

The file will be format like .

```
 Name: Johnny 
 Age : 23
 City: London
```

Code:

```
public void readFileForDataBaseCredentials() {
        Scanner newFile = null;
        try {
            newFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(selectedFile));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("could not find the file");
        }

        while (newFile.hasNext()) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: after semi-colon or colon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is too much for this. Just get the substring after the `:` character:

```
while (newFile.hasNext()) {
  String s = newFile.next();
  int ind = s.indexOf(":");
  if(ind != -1){
    String value = s.substring(ind); //value is what you want
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
(?<=:)\s*([\w ]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zW8aO2/1)**

You can also use

```
.*?:\s*([\w ]+)
```

or

```
[^:]+:\s*([\w ]+)
```

or just split on the basis of `:` and take the 2nd element

*Java Code*

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
String pattern = "(?<=:)\\s*([\\w ]+)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
while (true) {
     String line = x.nextLine();
     Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
     if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
     }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/amdIkR)**

Comment: @RomanVottner This is just regex not JAVA code..included JAVA code now

Answer (score 0):

It would be advisable if you write the code yourself.

HINT to get you started:

You can use a combination of JAVA`s indexOf and substring method to achieve the same

1) Read the file line by line
2) Get the index of `:` using the `indexOf(":")` method
3) Get substring using `substring(startindex)` method with startindex as index returned in 2nd step. This returned substring is what you need